# Adding a form to the admin menu

Tags: forms, hooks

Ive followed 3 tutorials and I cant seem to crack this. My goal is to create a form in the admin section to store some information.

I have used the following to create the form and call it from a url but I seem to be missing something

```
    function read_more_news_admin() {
  $form = array();
   //link field
      $form['link_container'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('some-class')),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
      );
      $form['link_container']['link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link_field',
        '#field_name' => 'link_field',
        '#language' => 'und',
        '#field_parents' => array(),
        '#delta' => 0,
        '#default_value' => array(
          'title' => variable_get('link_title', ''),
          'url' => variable_get('link_url', ''),
        ),
      );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function read_more_news_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/settings/readmorenews'] = array(
    'title' => 'Read More News Module Settings',
    'description' => 'Set read more news outgoing link here',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('read_more_news_admin'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer readmorenews settings'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
   );
  return $items;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since the path is `admin/*` so therefore it must show in the admin menu, once thing you can check is the access argument of the page, the link would appear in the admin menu only if the user have access to that page so once you can check after changing the `access arguments` to something more simple.

Comment: What do you suggest for the access arguments? I was just following a tutorial that placed that there. So I dont understand how to use it properly yet.

Comment: Actually `access arguments` contains the permission for the page, it depends upon you how you want to set the access control for that page, simplest you can try for now is `'access arguments' => array('access content'),` check more here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5968/whats-the-difference-between-access-arguments-and-access-callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function read_more_news_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/settings/readmorenews'] = array(
        'title' => 'Read More News Module Settings',
        'description' => 'Set read more news outgoing link here',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('read_more_news_admin_form'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer readmorenews settings'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );
    return $items;
}
function read_more_news_admin_form($form, &$form_state) {
    $form = array();
    $form['link_container'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('some-class')),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
    );
    $form['link_container']['link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link_field',
        '#field_name' => 'link_field',
        '#language' => 'und',
        '#field_parents' => array(),
        '#delta' => 0,
        '#default_value' => array(
            'title' => variable_get('link_title', ''),
            'url' => variable_get('link_url', ''),
        ),
    );
    return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Or check this url: https://www.drupal.org/node/1111260

```
function read_more_news_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer my module' => array(
      'title' => t('administer readmorenews settings'),
      'description' => t('Administer read more news settings.'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: No dice, the path admin/settings/readmorenews still does not exist. I have cleared cache, and reinstalled the module.

Comment: did you place the permission https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7